# errors in classes generated by JAXB from XSD

Tags: java, eclipse, jaxb, xsd

I use JAXB in eclipse Luna to generate Java classes from a third party XSD file. This file often defines a simple type which is just a primitive type. For instance:

```
<xsd:simpleType name="ChannelIdType">
  <xsd:restriction base="xsd:unsignedInt" />
</xsd:simpleType>
```

The simple type is then used for elements of a complex type, for instance:

```
<xsd:complexType name="DataRequestEntryType">
  <xsd:sequence>
    <xsd:element name="ChannelId" type="ChannelIdType" />
    <xsd:element name="IsChannelOpen" type="xsd:boolean" />
    ...
  </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
```

JAXB generates a Java class for the complex type that seems perfectly correct:

```
public class DataChannelEntryType {
  @XmlElement(name = "ChannelId")      <-- ERROR here, see below
  protected long channelId;
  @XmlElement(name = "IsChannelOpen")
  protected boolean isChannelOpen;
  ...
}
```

But, it also generates the following JAXB ERROR for the line @XmlElement(name = "ChannelId")

```
The expected XML type associated with 'long' is not valid for XML element 'ChannelId'.
```

Does anybody know what that error message means? I cannot change the XSD file, but what should one do to remove the error (short of removing the simple class, which anyway seems quite legal)? Or at least suppress the generation of the error?

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: When you are getting this error ?

Comment: Right after the code generation, the project is built automatically and the errors show up.

Comment: @NaveenRamawat I generated the Java classes using the xjc.exe included in the JDK, and I did not get any error. Also, the header of the class generated from eclipse specifies

Comment: @NaveenRamawat  _This file was generated by the JavaTM Architecture for XML Binding(JAXB) Reference Implementation, vhudson-jaxb-ri-2.2-147_, while the files generated from the JDK specify _This file was generated by the JavaTM Architecture for XML Binding(JAXB) Reference Implementation, v2.2.4-2_ Any idea why the difference? Could that explain the different behavior?

Comment: Seems your eclipse jaxb plugin pointing incompatible jaxb-ri files ..

Comment: @NaveenRamawat The jaxb plugin specifies the following files from eclipselink: com.sun.tools.xjc_2.2.0.jar,  com.sun.xml.bind_2.2.0v201004141950.jar and javax.xml.bind_2.2.0v201105210649.jar. Do I need to link to some different files?

Comment: @NaveenRamawat I removed the links to the eclipselink files and replaced the JRE System Library jre7 with the JDK1.7.0_55. Now the generated class is identical to the one generated directly using xjc.exe, but eclipse still shows the error message. It is not a dangling message: I cleared the Problems manually, but when I generate again the problems comes back. Any idea where the error message shown in eclipse is coming from ???

Comment: @NaveenRamawat I found the culprit: it is the eclipse JAXB Validator. If I disable it in the Window | Preferences | Validation pane, the error is no longer generated.

Answer (score 0):

Try  disabled  JAXB Validator.

Project -> Properties -> Validation -> Jaxb Validator